# PhoneGap offline forms and data storage with JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, forms, cordova, mobile

I'm trying to create an app which is basically just a long form, which then generates a PDF from the data collected. The app needs to be completely offline.

Is it possible to collect and store the data offline (I was thinking in local storage or using lawnchair) from forms without having to access a server. There will be around 100 seperate pieces of data to record.

Is there a framework or library that I could use for this, or any tutorials I could follow? Is it even possible in Phonegap??

Thanks!

Comment: use websql. it supports 50mb. Don't go for localStorage if it has more data's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage has a size limitation of 5 MB
So if you think your total data is less than 5 MB you can use it, it's easy to use.

If you need to save more data, I have two database for you. First one is I'm using for almost over a year. Didn't face any issue. [Brodysoft SQL wrapper plugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) It's use is just like web sql.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db"});
  // ...
}
```

I didn't use the second one but saw the reference in SO. Read that it's very efficient. [HTML5SQL](http://html5sql.com/)

```
$.get('Setup-Tables.SQL',function(sqlStatements){
    html5sql.process(
        //This is the text data from the SQL file you retrieved
        sqlStatements,
        function(){
            // After all statements are processed this function
            //   will be called.
        },
        function(error){
            // Handle any errors here
        }
    );
});
```

Between this two choice has to be yours.